# Swap Images is not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: image, swap, magento-1.9

i've uploaded an image to a single child product of a simple configurable product but it's not swapping when clicking on the swatch. 
can anyone help please?

Comment: Please provide more information or code to clarify what you have going on.

Comment: for example here: http://www.gardencosmetics.it/make-up/occhi/matite-occhi/matita-occhi.html i cannot make the images swap accordingly to the color selected on the swatch. If i should attach here some code, please let me know in which folder i can find the related one thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this comprehensive tutorial on how to add swatches into your product website. [Link to configurable swatches](http://sherodesigns.com/tutorial-configurable-swatches-in-magento/)

There is also a [YouTube tutorial on this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-AtFc92Wnc), which uses the built in function of Magento 1.9

Lastly, I suggest you add the `magento-1.9` tag to your question, or add more details regarding your code/structure so others can pinpoint the exact issue.

There are also paid options available, which you might want to consider if it's what you want: [extensionmall link for Magento](http://www.extensionsmall.com/)

Honestly I have not used this platform before. So again do add the tag and others can assist you.

Comment: thanks, the problem is not creating the swatch, the problem is swapping the images that is not working. I'll follow your advice and add the tag, hopefully someone could help me,thanks!